# Sharepoint 365 - How to provide access to a service account?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, office-365, security

my organisation has recently upgraded their Sharepoint to 365. Previous versions of Sharepoint had the facility to grant access to a service account (EMEA\xxx...), however it appears 365 can only grant access to users via an email address. Is this correct? If not, please can you let me know how I can provide access to the service account?

Thanks very much in advance for any help you can offer

Regards,

David

Answer (score 2):

To grant access to SharePoint to an internal account it must be a user in Office 365 with a licensed assigned.  Once you assign the license they will be available to grant access inside SharePoint. There is not difference between a live "User" and a "service" account as far as O365 goes.